# Merge two CSV's with unique columns in python

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files representing data from two different years.  I know how to do the basic merging using csvwriter and dictkeys,  but the problem lies here:  while the CSVs have mostly shared column headers, each may have unique columns.  If a species was caught in one year but not the other, that column would only be present in that year.  How can I merge the new data to the old data, creating new columns and padding the old data with zero in those columns?

File 1:     `"Date","Time","Species A","Species B", "Species X"`

File 2:     `"Date","Time", "Species A", "Species B", "Species C"`

I need the end result to be one csv with this header:
       "`Date","Time","Species A","Species B", "Species C", "Species X"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone else will probably post a solution using the `csv` module, so I'll give a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) solution for comparison purposes:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("fish1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("fish2.csv")

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).fillna(0)
df = df[["Date", "Time"] + list(df.columns[1:-1])]
df.to_csv("merged_fish.csv", index=False)
```

---

Explanation:

First, we read in the two files:

```
>>> df1 = pd.read_csv("fish1.csv")
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv("fish2.csv")
>>> df1
   Date  Time  Species A  Species B  Species X
0     1     2          3          4          5
1     6     7          8          9         10
2    11    12         13         14         15
>>> df2
   Date  Time  Species A  Species B  Species C
0    16    17         18         19         20
1    21    22         23         24         25
2    26    27         28         29         30
```

Then we simply concatenate them, which automatically fills the missing data with `NaN`:

```
>>> df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
>>> df
   Date  Species A  Species B  Species C  Species X  Time
0     1          3          4        NaN          5     2
1     6          8          9        NaN         10     7
2    11         13         14        NaN         15    12
0    16         18         19         20        NaN    17
1    21         23         24         25        NaN    22
2    26         28         29         30        NaN    27
```

You want them filled with 0 instead, so:

```
>>> df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).fillna(0)
>>> df
   Date  Species A  Species B  Species C  Species X  Time
0     1          3          4          0          5     2
1     6          8          9          0         10     7
2    11         13         14          0         15    12
0    16         18         19         20          0    17
1    21         23         24         25          0    22
2    26         28         29         30          0    27
```

This order isn't quite the one you asked for, though, you wanted `Time` and `Date` first, so:

```
>>> df = df[["Date", "Time"] + list(df.columns[1:-1])]
>>> df
   Date  Time  Species A  Species B  Species C  Species X
0     1     2          3          4          0          5
1     6     7          8          9          0         10
2    11    12         13         14          0         15
0    16    17         18         19         20          0
1    21    22         23         24         25          0
2    26    27         28         29         30          0
```

And then we save it as a CSV file:

```
>>> df.to_csv("merged_fish.csv", index=False)
```

producing

```
Date,Time,Species A,Species B,Species C,Species X
1,2,3,4,0.0,5.0
6,7,8,9,0.0,10.0
11,12,13,14,0.0,15.0
16,17,18,19,20.0,0.0
21,22,23,24,25.0,0.0
26,27,28,29,30.0,0.0
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly, thank you!  Pandas seems like it'll be very useful for other things I need as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `csv` module solution in Python 3:

```
import csv

# Generate some data...

csv1 = '''\
Date,Time,Species A,Species B,Species C
04/01/2012,13:00,1,2,3
04/02/2012,13:00,1,2,3
04/03/2012,13:00,1,2,3
04/04/2012,13:00,1,2,3
'''

csv2 = '''\
Date,Time,Species A,Species B,Species X
04/01/2013,13:00,1,2,3
04/02/2013,13:00,1,2,3
04/03/2013,13:00,1,2,3
04/04/2013,13:00,1,2,3
'''

with open('2012.csv','w') as f:
    f.write(csv1)
with open('2013.csv','w') as f:
    f.write(csv2)

# The actual program

years = ['2012.csv','2013.csv']

lines = []
headers = set()
for year in years:
    with open(year,'r',newline='') as f:
        r = csv.DictReader(f)
        lines.extend(list(r))                 # Merge lines from all files.
        headers = headers.union(r.fieldnames) # Collect unique column names.

# Sort the unique headers keeping Date,Time columns first.
new_headers = ['Date','Time'] + sorted(headers - set(['Date','Time']))

with open('result.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    # The 3rd parameter is the default if the key isn't present.
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,new_headers,0)
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(lines)

# View the result

with open('result.csv') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
Date,Time,Species A,Species B,Species C,Species X
04/01/2012,13:00,1,2,3,0
04/02/2012,13:00,1,2,3,0
04/03/2012,13:00,1,2,3,0
04/04/2012,13:00,1,2,3,0
04/01/2013,13:00,1,2,0,3
04/02/2013,13:00,1,2,0,3
04/03/2013,13:00,1,2,0,3
04/04/2013,13:00,1,2,0,3
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), it looks like you should be able to read out both files, merge the keys from the 2 extracted dictionaries, then use the `fieldnames` and `restval` params on the writer to achieve your 0 defaults.